# post a data in SharePoint list gives 400 Bad request

Tags: angular, angularjs, forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

here is my sharepoint service.ts angular component code

i have my form code deployed in my sharepoint
i want to post the data to my sharepoint list ,
here i am able to fetch data from sharepoint list and unable to post the data
in my console getting below error

> polyfills.js:1   POST
> https://sharepoint-base-url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list-name')/items
> 400 (Bad Request)

```
export class SharepointService {
  private BaseUrl = 'sharepoint-url';
  private listName = 'list-name';
  private urlEncoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec;

  private userIdSource = new BehaviorSubject<string | undefined>(undefined);
  userId = this.userIdSource.asObservable();

  private usernameSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  currentUsername = this.usernameSource.asObservable();

  private projectSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  currentProject = this.projectSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.urlEncoder = new HttpUrlEncodingCodec();
  }

  changeUsername(username: string) {
    this.usernameSource.next(username);
  }

  changeProject(project: string) {
    this.projectSource.next(project);
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });

    return this.http
      .get<any>(
        `${this.BaseUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.listName}')/items`,
        { headers }
      )
      .pipe(
        tap((data) => console.log('Data from SharePoint:', data)),
        catchError((error: any) => {
          console.error('Error fetching data from SharePoint:', error);
          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
  }

 // postData(formData: any): Observable<any> {
  //     let url = `${this.BaseUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.listName}')/items`;
  //     const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  //       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  //       'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
  //       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  //   });
  //       const dataToPost = {
  //         Title: formData.userid,
  //         Level: formData.level,
  //         Project: formData.projectClient,
  //       };
  //       console.log('Data to post:', dataToPost);
  //       return this.http.post<any>(url, dataToPost, { headers });
  //     // return this.http.post<any>(`${this.BaseUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.listName}')/items?$select=enterprise ID`, { headers });
  //   }
  // }



  postData(formData: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.BaseUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.listName}')/items`;
    const digestUrl = `${this.BaseUrl}/_api/contextinfo`;
    return this.http
      .post<any>(
        digestUrl,
        {},
        { headers: { Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose' } }
      )
      .pipe(
        switchMap((digestData) => {
          const digestValue =
            digestData.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

          const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'X-RequestDigest': digestValue,
          });

          const dataToPost = {
            Title: formData.username,
            Project: formData.project,
          };
          console.log('Data to post:', dataToPost);

          return this.http.post<any>(url, dataToPost, { headers });
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I need solution for the below error in my sharepoint console
polyfills.js:1

> POST
> https://sharepoint-url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list-name')/items
> 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: try to console `console.log('URL:', url);
console.log('headers:', headers);console.log('digest :', digestData);` and check these values ,are they correct

Answer (score 0):

check following api to post a item

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.List"
  },
  "AllowContentTypes": true,
  "BaseTemplate": 100,
 "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
 "Description": "My list description",
 "Title": "Test"
}
```